# How do I get just the date here using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

DATA:

```
"Sun Sep 30 2012 12:37:24 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
```

In Regex, I'm trying to just get "Sep 30 2012" without making a literal `/Sep\s\d\d\s2012/`

I want to pretty much take out "Sun " and " 12:37:24...." so that only "Sep 30 2012" is captured.

**How would I do this in JavaScript REGEX?**

UPDATE:

I made one, but it's not that elegant: `\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s2\d\d\d`

***Is there a REGEX pattern that can say, "take out the first 3 letters and one space after it... capture the date format... don't take anything afterwards."***

Comment: btw, ...do folks not like regex? most answers i get are string methods...

Comment: regex is great for some things, but it's relatively expensive (compared to simple string methods); but honestly? For this? Why not just [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that the day and month are always 3 characters long, so the searched string has always the same length and is always at the same position.

```
"Sun Sep 30 2012 12:37:24 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)".slice(4, 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't. I can see that you're almost certainly using some JavaScript date-to-string conversion (maybe even just `(new Date).toString()`) and that is locale-dependent. It will be different for many users of the script.

Instead the date should already be in a specific format. Such as in PHP you can do `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` and then use as is or `split(/[- :]/)`. Or if you already have the Date object, just use the `get*()` functions.

If I am wrong and your format is actually exactly that every time regardless of locale, then I guess something like this would do: `/[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{2} \d{4}/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` , `splice` and `join`

```
var date = "Sun Sep 30 2012 12:37:24 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" ;
var desiredResult = date.split(" ").splice(1, 3).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `substring`:

```
var s = "Sun Sep 30 2012 12:37:24 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)";
s = s.substring(4, 15); // "Sep 30 2012"
```

If you really insist on using a regular expression, you could use:

```
s = s.match(/\w{3}\s(\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s2\d{3})/)[1]; // "Sep 30 2012"
```

But quite honestly, dates are not really meant to be parsed with a regular expression, or `substring` for that matter, but with real `Date` [parsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: thank you. i know I can use other things besides regex, but I'm trying to learn regex in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question "how to say three letters and a space in JS":

```
> "abc ".match("[A-Za-z]{3} ")
["abc "]
> "ab3 ".match("[A-Za-z]{3} ")
null
```